# Lambda capture scope

Tags: c++

I'm struggling to understand the scope and ownership of lambda captures, why does the following code work?:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    void setCallback(std::function<void()> f) { callback = std::move(f); }

    void trigger() { callback(); }

private:
    std::function<void()> callback;
};

struct Bar {
    int i;

    Bar(int i) : i{i} { std::cout << "bar constructed" << std::endl; }

    ~Bar() { std::cout << "bar destroyed" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo{};

    { // scope
        Bar bar{1};
        foo.setCallback([&bar]() { std::cout << bar.i << std::endl; });
        bar.i = 2;
    } //end of scope, bar gets deleted

    foo.trigger();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
bar constructed 
bar destroyed
2
```

Is the compiler inlining `bar.i` in the lambda function statically? I'm capturing by reference, what is going on?

Comment: It is UB, so seems to work is a possible result.

Comment: It is "randomly" working. As your trace show,  `bar.i` is called after bar has been destroyed. By capturing by reference you are passing the address of a local variable which has already been descoped when it is accessed.

Comment: thanks! is it possible that `bar` is being copied somewhere? perhaps std::function is making a copy of it?

Comment: Not is not copied anywhere. You are accessing a dangling reference. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Your code does not work because bar is descoped before the lambda that captured it is executed. The lambda uses a dangling reference. Here is an updated sample that will convince you, that if it works in your example it is simply because nothing else has been allocated at the address where bar was initially stored.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo {
    void setCallback(std::function<void()> f) { callback = std::move(f); }

    void trigger() { callback(); }

private:
    std::function<void()> callback;
};

struct Bar {
    int i;

    Bar(int i) : i{i} { std::cout << "bar constructed" << std::endl; }

    ~Bar() { std::cout << "bar destroyed" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo{};

    { // scope
        Bar bar{1};
        foo.setCallback([&bar]() { std::cout << bar.i << std::endl; });
        bar.i = 2;
    } //end of scope, bar gets deleted
    
    volatile int  a = 5;  // allocate something after bar is destroyed
    
    foo.trigger();
    return 0;
}
```

Now you will get:

```
bar constructed 
bar destroyed
5
```

5 is the next value allocated on the stack in place of bar.

Comment: I just tried this, I still get '2' every time (using clang)

Comment: Running here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler I get 5. It is possible your compiler optimized the volatile but I doubt it.

Comment: got it, so the compiler is doing some magic and I was right expecting it not to work! thanks for the example!